# Is there any way to fix this error 'google is not defined'

Tags: javascript, google-maps, laravel-5

I'm using [Distant Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro) to calculate the distance between places and suggestions. I'm using a script on the index blade which prompts `'google is not defined'`.

**Code snippet:**

```
function initialize() {
  var input = document.getElementById('searchloc');
  var options = {
    types: ['geocode'], // this should work!
    componentRestrictions: {country: "ae"}
  };
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);     
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to do it by **removing**:

- google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
- &callback=initialize"
- async defer

and then by **adding**:

- &libraries=places
- onload="initialize()"

So the whole code looks like this:

```
<body onload="initialize()">
    <input type="text" id="searchloc" />
    <script>
      var map;
      function initialize() {
          var input = document.getElementById('searchloc');
          var options = {
            types: ['geocode'], // this should work!
            componentRestrictions: {country: "ae"}
          };
          var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options); 
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBJSAn2t5Aosg0yhwXxbf6tRvQXmS8vDKU&libraries=places"></script>
  </body>
```

Link to demo: https://jsbin.com/dutewup/edit?html,output

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error "google is not defined" while using Gmap3. The problem was that I was including 'gmap3' before including 'google', so I reversed the order:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/gmap3.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also call your function within window load function,

```
$(function(){
   $(window).load(function(){
       //Here is my logic now
   });
});
```

Comment: Actually I'm getting positive result, only if  I refresh the page several times

Answer (score 0):

you should add this line

< script  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jskey=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initialize"
< /script>

remove  this line google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Google API to calculate the distance. If you have latitude and longitude, you can do it mathematically -

visit:

https://www.geodatasource.com/developers/javascript

Comment: My code depends on this , so i'm not able change the code , but thanks